# Polynomials as infinite series of exponentials.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to express polynomials as exponentials in sort of a reverse Taylor series? I think Stone-Weierstrass says this is so, but looking for something constructive.

$e^x=1+x+x^2/2! +x^3/3!+...$

$e^{2x}=1+2x+(4x^2)/2!+(8x^3)/3!+...$

In general, the coefficient of the $k_{th}$ degree term of the polynomial for $e^{px}$ is $M_{pk}=p^k/k!$.

Let $x^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{nk}e^{kx}$.  Is there a way to find $c_{nk}$ at least for allowed values of $x$?

$C(n,k)$ are the binomial coefficients.

What I've tried so far.

I think there might be a way. $(e^x-1)^n$ is a lower triangular matrix in the $e^x$ basis having element values $P^{-1}_{nk}=C(n,k)(-1)^{n-k}$ for $n_{th}$ row and $k_{th}$ column.$P_{nk} =C(n,k)$ It's also lower triangular for the $x$ basis. In both cases the terms on the diagonal are $1$. Their determinants are 1 and so non-zero. $P^{-1}\vec{e}=L\vec{x}=P^{-1}M\vec{x}$.

If lower triangular matrices that are invertible have inverses calculable in finite time, then it seems possible to find $M^{-1}$.

Since $PL=M$. M consists of the Taylor coefficients, P the binomial coefficients. Requiring L to be lower triangular uniquely determines L, but I haven't found a simple formula. I think its:
$L_{nk}=\sum_{j=0}^n C(n,j)(-1)^{n-j}j^k/k!$

The inverse of a lower triangular matrix is lower triangular, so again we have a process by which to use $L (L^{-1})=I$ to calculate elements of the first $N$ rows of $L^{-1}$ in finite time. $M^{-1}=L^{-1}P^{-1}$

Maybe with Fourier Series?

By Fourier Series:
$x^2=\frac{L^2}{3}+\frac{4L^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\cos{(\frac{k\pi x}{L})}, -L\le x\le L$

So $-x^2=\frac{L^2}{3}+\frac{2L^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}(e^{k\pi x/L}+e^{-k\pi x/L})$

$v=x\pi/L\implies v^2=\frac{-\pi^2}{3}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}(e^{kv}+e^{-kv})$

$v^2=-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}(e^{kv}+e^{-kv})+1}{k^2}, -\pi\le v \le \pi$

Might have something:

$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+..., -1<x<1$

$\ln{1+x} = x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+..., -1<x<1$

Let $e^y=1+x$.

Then $y=(e^y-1)-(e^y-1)^2/2+(e^y-1)^3/3-(e^y-1)^4/4+..., -\infty<y<\ln{2}$

But, what's the constant term? Looks like it would be the negative sum of the harmonic series which doesn't converge. Yet the graph shows convergence:

[image: Convergence of exponential series]

Comment: There might be a formal inverse, but as functions this won't work: as $x\to-\infty$ the series will converge to $c_{nk}$ (or else not converge at all), while $x^n$ will not converge to a constant (if $n>0$).